# .Net Core server controlled media streaming

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, audio-streaming, asp.net-core-signalr

I have to write a web application that can stream audio media to the clients. The hard part is that **the server needs to control the streaming**, so I can not give a simple mp3 (or something like that) to the client as 'application/octet-stream'. The basic requirements are:

- Every client can listen to every track only once. If I give to the clients an mp3, they can just download it and play it as many times as they want. There is a possibility for the clients to play the track more than once, but in this case, only the server can approve this.
- The streaming needs to be continuous, so after the client initiated the 'start', they can not skip forward or go back in the track.
- We are not and will not support seeking and playbacks, so the solution needs to fit only for this scenario, it does not have to be universal, but it needs to be scalable very well.

The current setup is that we have an Angular 6 client-side app and an Asp.Net Core 2.1 backend with SignalR for the real-time communication (currently for other use cases only). My questions are:

1. The new SignalR has some capability to "stream data" (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/streaming?view=aspnetcore-2.1) but I did not find anything that proves this can handle my scenario (we will have big loads, maybe even thousands of truly concurrent listenings). Is this streaming feature designed for this?

   If SignalR would not be the right choice, could somebody point me in the right direction? An optimal solution also would stay on the .net core stack.
2. How can the client play the stream? I am not familiar with the audio codecs. If I just chuck my track into 100 or 1000 pieces and I send the first one to the client, is it already playable?

Thanks in advance.

edit: The client is on computers in a private LAN. They will have no access to the internet (so they can not use for example flash-based recording tools from other sites). They will also have no elevated rights on the computer, so they can not install recording tools. We does not need to be bulletproof, but we need some protection against the trivial and easy to do "attacks".

Comment: _Every client can listen every track only once. If I give to the clients an mp3, they can just download it and play it as many times as they want_ You can forget that, especially on desktop. If a user wants to play it more often, he can so either by recording the sound while it plays or by dumping the traffic as it is streamed from the server which is a childs play on desktop. Mobile Apps may give you a bit more "subjective protection", but then download wouldn't matter neither cause app data is harder accessible anyways

Comment: Sorry, I forgot a really important detail :) I updated my question.

Comment: Is everyone hearing the same thing at the same time?  And if not, if they can control it anyway, then there's little point in any sort of protection because they can just request the data from the server.

Comment: They are not hearing the thing at the same time, but obviously they are authenticated users, so the server can tell if somebody already listened a track or not. Please do not get stuck in security issues, that was not my question at all.

Comment: @PeterHurtony It absolutely is your question.  2 out of 3 of the requirements points are security related.  Answers to these details matter if you want a system that actually meets those requirements.

Comment: My 3 bullet points were functional requirements, that is how the application should work. I can not give you a complete specification, cuz it would be 40 pages but I am not worried about the security. If I could achive such behaviour I described, it would be enough.

Comment: how did you handle this?

Comment: we basically implemented our own adaptive streaming x) didn't find any half-baked solution at that point